# Some Images not loading on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an app running in production on heroku and for some odd reason the images associated with the rating system aren't loading. In other words, users have the ability to rate movies and there should be 5 star images displayed and they can choose how many stars that they rate the movie.

Now the stars show perfectly fine in development but this is how they appear in production:

[image: production image error]

When I right click and inspect element it says "Failed to load the given url"

I've also run these:

```
locally: rake assets:precompile
locally: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
production: heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and the images still aren't displaying, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

edit (so the path is wrong, now i should be using asset_path for the images but they're in a query plugin!!! How do I get around this so they can be pulled from the asset_path? BTW, they're star-off.png:

```
$.fn.raty.defaults = {
        cancel          : false,
        cancelHint      : 'cancel this rating!',
        cancelOff       : 'cancel-off.png',
        cancelOn        : 'cancel-on.png',
        cancelPlace     : 'left',
        click           : undefined,
        half            : false,
        halfShow        : true,
        hints           : ['bad', 'poor', 'regular', 'good', 'gorgeous'],
        iconRange       : undefined,
        mouseover       : undefined,
        noRatedMsg      : 'not rated yet',
        number          : 5,
        path            : 'img/',
        precision       : false,
        round           : { down: .25, full: .6, up: .76 },
        readOnly        : false,
        score           : undefined,
        scoreName       : 'score',
        single          : false,
        size            : 16,
        space           : true,
        starHalf        : 'star-half.png',
        starOff         : 'star-off.png',
        starOn          : 'star-on.png',
        target          : undefined,
        targetFormat    : '{score}',
        targetKeep      : false,
        targetText      : '',
        targetType      : 'hint',
        width           : undefined
    };
```

Comment: Inspect the html and see where it's trying to load the images from.  Then see if there's anything actually at that location.

Comment: You've certainly pointed me in the right direction, see updated post.

Comment: Can you pick a single non-working image and just work with that?  Say where the src is set to, and where it actually is on your filesystem relative to your <project>/public folder.

Comment: So the source is: /assets/star-off.png but in reality, it should probably be stored in an Amazon S3 bucket like the rest. But because the asset_path is not being used I think it's causing the issue. How do we get it to upload to S3, I'm confused because it's in the actual JQuery.

Comment: Fixed it with cancelOff  : "<%= asset_url 'cancel-off.png' %>",
 +  cancelOn  : "<%= asset_url 'cancel-on.png' %>", Add yours as an answer if you want and ill accept. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: My answer was more like a general debugging tip.  If your solution will help other people using that plugin then it's better if you write your own solution up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and ended up just correcting the link direct in the raty.js with the actual precompiled links...

```
    starHalf        : 'star-half.png',
    starOff         : 'star-off.png',
    starOn          : 'star-on.png',
```

to this

```
starHalf     : 'star-half-db15fb9b3561d5c741d8aea9ef4f0957bd9bc51aa1caa6d7a5c316e083c1abd5.png',
starOff      : 'star-off-6aaeebdaab93d594c005d366ce0d94fba02e7a07fd03557dbee8482f04a91c22.png',
starOn       : 'star-on-fd26bf0ea0990cfd808f7540f958eed324b86fc609bf56ec2b3a5612cdfde5f5.png',
```

That fixed my issue and got the starts to show correctly on Heroku after I recompiled everything.